# Expand ListView not working while adding button

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I tried Expand ListView method from using the code from the following blog, https://wirasetiawan29.wordpress.com/2016/01/20/membuat-expand-listview-material-design-di-android/

Everything works fine. But if I add a button in FrameLayout then the touchevent for listview item not works properly. Also I tried changing FrameLayout to Relative & also to Linear, but still no success.

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_below="@+id/rl_title_wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/deskripsi"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="Share"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to Frame Layout [description by Google's documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)...

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display
>   a single item. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a single
>   child view, because it can be difficult to organize child views in a
>   way that's scalable to different screen sizes without the children
>   overlapping each other. You can, however, add multiple children to a
>   FrameLayout and control their position within the FrameLayout by
>   assigning gravity to each child, using the android:layout_gravity
>   attribute.

Hence, your original TextView is actually overlapping by the Button (Share). You can use **android:layout_gravity="right"** to position the button in the right end of the screen, however, then you will have to fix the maxium length of string for TextView, so that it doesn't get overlap by the Button on the right.

If you don't have any problem, might I suggest you to use LinearLayout? It's easier to handle and render by the GPU (As far as I know). Here's an example code of your item...

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/wrapper"
 android:layout_below="@+id/rl_title_wrapper"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/deskripsi"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center"
    android:text="This is a big chunk of description for your listView item. you can write as much as you want...."
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
 <Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Share"
    android:layout_gravity="right|center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

You can also use RelativeLayout and GridLayout here. 
I hope it answers your question. Cheers!

Comment: I already tried this and also with Relative Layout, but no success.

Comment: It probably has nothing to with your UI. You should provide your adapter code/viewholders code where you have handled your on click listener